# SailsJS error installing MongoDB (windows 8 x64)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-8, sails.js, waterline

Currently i have a MongoDB installed in my system which is working great with my PHP projects. But when i am installing mongodb adapter for sailsjs it gives me an error

`gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
        gyp info spawn args   '-f',
        gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
        gyp info spawn args   '-G',
        gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2012',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\web\\app\\build\\config.gypi',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Rusty Orange\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modu
        les\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Rusty Orange\\.node-gyp\\0.10.25\\common.gypi'
        ,
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Rusty Orange\\.node-gyp\\0.10.
        25',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\web\\app',
        gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
        gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
        gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\web\\app\\build',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
        gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\web\app) while trying to load binding.gyp
        gyp ERR! configure error
        gyp ERR! stack Error:`gyp` failed with exit code: 1
        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Rusty Orange\AppData\Roami
        ng\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:343:16)
        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:
        12)
        gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
        gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Users\Rusty Orange\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
        dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--msvs_version=2012"
        gyp ERR! cwd C:\web\app
        gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
        gyp ERR! not ok

```
    C:\web\app>npm install sails-mongo -msvs_version=2012
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-errors
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.4.4
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-cursor
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-cursor
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.4.4
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-errors
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.8
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.8

    > kerberos@0.0.3 install C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongod
    b\node_modules\kerberos
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>n
    ode "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modul
    es\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
    argets(64,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform T
    oolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build tools, please i
    nstall Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the c
    urrent Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the sol
    ution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...". [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails
    -mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

    > bson@0.2.8 install C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
    de_modules\bson
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\n
    ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
    argets(64,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform T
    oolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build tools, please i
    nstall Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the c
    urrent Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the sol
    ution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...". [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails
    -mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    sails-mongo@0.10.4 node_modules\sails-mongo
    ├── waterline-errors@0.10.0-rc1
    ├── async@0.8.0
    ├── waterline-cursor@0.0.5 (async@0.9.0)
    ├── lodash@2.4.1
    └── mongodb@1.4.4 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.8)

    C:\web\app>npm install sails-mongo --save
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.4.4
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-cursor
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-errors
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-errors
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.4.4
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/waterline-cursor
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.8
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.8
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3

    > kerberos@0.0.3 install C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongod
    b\node_modules\kerberos
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>n
    ode "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modul
    es\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
      kerberos.cc
      worker.cc
      security_credentials.cc
      security_buffer.cc
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\worker.cc) [C:\web\app
    \node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerb
    eros.vcxproj]
      security_buffer_descriptor.cc
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\web\a
    pp\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\ke
    rberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' (..\li
    b\win32\kerberos.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\
    node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
      security_context.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa
    rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
    Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modul
    es\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxpro
    j]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa
    rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
    Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\web\app\node_
    modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.v
    cxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buff
    er.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\k
    erberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' (..\li
    b\win32\wrappers\security_buffer.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_
    modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa
    rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
    Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buffer_descriptor.cc) [C:\web\app
    \node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerb
    eros.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa
    rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
    Specify /EHsc (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_context.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modu
    les\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxpr
    oj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_cred
    entials.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modu
    les\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' (..\li
    b\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\
    node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_buff
    er_descriptor.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\nod
    e_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' (..\li
    b\win32\wrappers\security_buffer_descriptor.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-
    mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_cont
    ext.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\
    kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' (..\li
    b\win32\wrappers\security_context.cc) [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node
    _modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
      kerberos_sspi.c
      base64.c
         Creating library C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\
      node_modules\kerberos\build\Release\kerberos.lib and object C:\web\app\node_m
      odules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\Release\k
      erberos.exp
      Generating code
      Finished generating code
      kerberos.vcxproj -> C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\
      node_modules\kerberos\build\Release\\kerberos.node
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

    > bson@0.2.8 install C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
    de_modules\bson
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\n
    ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
      bson.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa
    rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
    Specify /EHsc [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_mo
    dules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\node
    _modules\nan\nan.h(1103): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size
    _t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_m
    odules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\node
    _modules\nan\nan.h(1117): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size
    _t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_m
    odules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    ..\ext\bson.cc(891): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'u
    int32_t', possible loss of data [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modul
    es\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\node
    _modules\nan\nan.h(950): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int64_t'
    to 'double', possible loss of data [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_mo
    dules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
              ..\ext\bson.cc(560) : see reference to function template instantiatio
      n 'v8::Local<v8::Number> NanNew<v8::Number,int64_t>(P)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  P=int64_t
              ]
    ..\ext\bson.cc(313): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' t
    o 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_m
    odules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
              ..\ext\bson.cc(142) : while compiling class template member function
      'void BSONSerializer<CountStream>::SerializeValue(void *,const v8::Handle<v8:
      :Value> &)'
              ..\ext\bson.cc(112) : see reference to function template instantiatio
      n 'void BSONSerializer<CountStream>::SerializeValue(void *,const v8::Handle<v
      8::Value> &)' being compiled
              ..\ext\bson.cc(92) : while compiling class template member function '
      void BSONSerializer<CountStream>::SerializeDocument(const v8::Handle<v8::Valu
      e> &)'
              ..\ext\bson.cc(869) : see reference to function template instantiatio
      n 'void BSONSerializer<CountStream>::SerializeDocument(const v8::Handle<v8::V
      alue> &)' being compiled
              ..\ext\bson.cc(868) : see reference to class template instantiation '
      BSONSerializer<CountStream>' being compiled
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent
    <v8::Object>::New(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)' [C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo
    \node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\Rusty Orange\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C450
    6: no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::
    Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>)' [C:\we
    b\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\bso
    n.vcxproj]
         Creating library C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\
      node_modules\bson\build\Release\bson.lib and object C:\web\app\node_modules\s
      ails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\Release\bson.exp
      Generating code
      Finished generating code
      bson.vcxproj -> C:\web\app\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node
      _modules\bson\build\Release\\bson.node
    sails-mongo@0.10.4 node_modules\sails-mongo
    ├── waterline-errors@0.10.0-rc1
    ├── async@0.8.0
    ├── waterline-cursor@0.0.5 (async@0.9.0)
    ├── lodash@2.4.1
    └── mongodb@1.4.4 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.8)

    C:\web\app>`
```

Does it has conflict with Visual Studio? or do i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of nodejs you installed on your system..This is the error of when conflict the sailjs version with nodejs version.

Check all the dependencies and then you may proceed.

You change  the version of nodejs directly using nvm(node version manager).

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for your response.. i change the version of nodeJs from x64 to x32 because i figure out that the visual c++ installed in my machine was 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

No, just change version of npm using nvm i am not telling about nodejs software version..

search nvm in internet definetely you will get idea

Thanks.

Comment: i already change the version of npm first and i got no luck.. changing the version of node works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check all the dependencies and then you may proceed.

You change the version of nodejs directly using nvm(node version manager).